# The flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK clears any task that is associated with the activity. What about tasks not associated with the activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, back-stack

My app has a few tasks, some of which are not associated with the current activity. So  `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` is useless because it doesn't clear those other tasks.

How can I clear all tasks in my app (regardless if they associate with the current activity) when launching a new activity?

I've tried everything online, and the only thing that works is using finish(), but I don't want to use that. Any other way?

Comment: Please explain why you have multiple tasks. This isn't usually necessary and causes lots of nasty side-effects.

Comment: The third-party library, Branch.io calls the intent in a new task. So I don't think I have any other way.

Comment: How do you know that you have multiple tasks? Please post the contents of your manifest and explain.